# React doesn't display all of my array from state

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, components, state

I'm trying to build a news reader for personal purposes ( and to practice what I learnt ), and I'm having troubles with the list of my articles, which I'm fetching from NewsApi and Reddit front page. I don't have an API since I think it'd be useless to create one just to fetch articles, and I'm not storing them, so it's all in my React app.

Here's the code :

```
componentDidMount() {
let posts = [];

fetch(`https://www.reddit.com/r/all.json`)
.then(resp => resp.json())
.then(redditAllPosts => {
  redditAllPosts.data.children.map((redditSinglePost) => {
    const { author, title, subreddit, permalink, created_utc } = redditSinglePost.data;
    let redditPost = {
      'sourcePost': 'Reddit',
      'date': created_utc,
      'title': title,
      'author': author,
      'url': `https://www.reddit.com${permalink}`,
      'subredditUrl': `https://www.reddit.com/r/${subreddit}`,
    };
    posts.push(redditPost);
  })
})

fetch(`https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&apiKey=${process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY}`)
.then(resp => resp.json())
.then(newsApiPosts => {
  newsApiPosts.articles.map((newsApiSinglePost) => {
    const dateNewsApiPost = moment(newsApiSinglePost.publishedAt).unix();
    const { author, title, url } = newsApiSinglePost;
    let newsApiPost = {
      'sourcePost': 'NewsApi',
      'date': dateNewsApiPost,
      'title': title,
      'author': author,
      'url': url,
      'sourceNews': newsApiSinglePost.source.name
    };
    posts.push(newsApiPost);
  })
  return posts;
})
.then(posts => {
  this.setState({posts})
})
}

constructor() {
 super()
 this.state = {
   posts: null,
   filtersTheme: null, ( will be implemented later )
   filtersCountry: null ( will be implemented later )
 }
}
```

So basically once the app is mounted, it fetches posts from Reddit, maps over what was fetched and pushes the article formatted my way to a posts array, and it does the same with NewsAPI posts. Once this is done, the program sets the state I tried to console log pretty much everything at every step. It logs the full array with 20 NewsAPI posts and 45 Reddit posts, but it only displays the first 20 posts of the array. The wrapped-up line of the logs is like this :

(20) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]

Where could that come from ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead:

```
this.setState(prevState => ({ posts: [...prevState.posts, ...posts] })
```

This way you only add to the posts in the state, and not overwrite them.

Comment: So you mean I should add the posts as they come instead ? Won't this provoke a re-render everytime one is added ?

Comment: Yes. To get arount this, you might have to track in state which responses have been received, and use that to wait to render.

Comment: Wow I'm really lost with all this prevState syntax, I'll look into it, thanks a lot for your answer ! Also how can I track which articles have been fetched, and how can I wait before triggering a render ? Without really giving me the code, that's my issue haha but just a track to follow, I'm completely lost and it's getting advanced compared to what I did so far in React ! Thanks !